# Auto-refrescar un token de acceso

Tags: php, api, postman

Al hacer una solicitud a una API, solamente me proporciona el url del token, client id, client secret, pero no me da el token de refresco que es lo que necesito para que en mi proyecto se actualice automáticamente el token de acceso y no tener que cambiarlo cada 24 horas manualmente desde Postman o Insomnia.
Esto es lo que tengo en mi proyecto en el archivo PHP y que manualmente tengo que cambiar el token:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'apikey: ***********************',
'Authorization: Bearer *token de acceso*',
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Cookie: *******************************************************'
```

),

En Postman me aparece esto y aún cuando cambio el token, me sigue apareciendo bloqueada la opción para autorefrescar el token de acceso:
[image]

Comment: Duda, quien desarrollo la API a la que te conectas?

Comment: La API es de estafeta